# Does word2vec have context between sentences?

Tags: word2vec

The word2vec system wants each sentence on a line by itself.  Does the context continue from one sentence to the next in the input file.  That is, does the first word in a sentence get context from the previous line? I'm wondering if I need to care about the order of the sentence in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should - but it may depend on your implementation though. Ideally, a word2vec learner should take as input something like a sequence of words and output a dictionary with entries those words.

This is actually quite important because a significant part of the job can be done before if you have a good tokenizer that may automatically erase stop-words, or even lemmatize.

You might want to have a glance at Spark's implementation which is - for me at least - way easier to understand than the C implementation.

Comment: I've just been using the C implementation

Comment: @cschmidt: It is not necessarily wise to apply stop-word filtering and lemmatization to word2vec models. This is because with enough data, word2vec models should adequately start picking up grammatical punctuation. For example, the sentence "The man is healthy" contains a wealth of information about the man's well being. Removing "is" loses the grammatical connection between "man" and "healthy," which would be instrumental for determining whether the man IS or IS NOT healthy.

Comment: @AlexR. do you have more knowledge about preprocessing that should be applied before Word2Vec? In my experiments, lemmatization made my vector space sparser (logical...) and the results a bit better but maybe it was because I did not have enough samples (about 200 000 journalistic articles). Erasing stop words is not a good idea indeed I figured out.